# storing a c++ string into a char* vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to store this string into a vector of pointers. This is just the starting point of the code. Eventually the vector will store words the user types in and either add it to the vector if the vector doesn't have it or show the word is already in the vector.

I tried to use strcpy() but then it told me to use strcpy_s(). So I did now and now it just crashes every time with no error. Can someone give me some insight into what is going on here.

```
vector<char*> wordBank;

string str;
cin >> str;

wordBank[0] = new char[str.length() + 1];
strcpy_s(wordBank[0], str.length() + 1 , str.c_str() );

cout << wordBank[0];

delete[] wordBank[0];
```

Comment: You never preserved any space in your `wordBank` vector, though accessing `wordBank[0]`. Try that code with `vector<char*> wordBank(1);`

Comment: Or use `wordBank.push_back(new char[str.length() + 1]);` instead.

Comment: I suppose we can't talk you into a nice `vector` of `string`, can we?

Comment: Why doesn't cin >> str; work for me? "No operator ">>" matches these operands.

Comment: Why do I have to include <string> for my compiler to recognise std::string::operator>> if I can create a string object just fine, meaning I already have the class definition?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice It seems you get the actual implementation in `<xstring>`, but additional stuff like `operator<<` overloads are in `<string>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418841/differences-among-including-xstring-cstring-string-and-wstring-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

I would not consider `vector<char*> wordBank;` this c++ code, but rather C code that happens to use some C++ features.

The standard library in C++ can make your life easier. You should use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

```
vector<string> wordBank;
wordBank.push_back(str);
```

It avoid all the pointer stuff, so you need not to do memory management (which is a good reason get rid of the pointers).

For `strcpy_s`, it's a safer version of `strcpy`, because you have to explicitly specify the size of the target buffer, which can avoid buffer overflows during copies.

However, `strcpy_s` is non-standard and MS specific, **NEVER** use `strcpy_s` unless your just want your code compiled on MSVS. Use `std::copy` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The default size of a `vector` is 0

Hence this line

```
vector<char*> wordBank;
```

just defines a 0 sized `vector` of character pointers

As people have mentioned in comments you can go with either of these  2 options:-

```
  vector<char*> wordBank(1);
```

OR

```
wordBank.push_back(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `char*` elements in the vector. You can use `string` instead, and append your strings to the vector with `push_back()`, which will allocate the needed space:

```
vector<string> wordBank;
string str;

cin >> str;
wordBank.push_back(str);
cout << wordBank[0];
```

This will free you from the burden of having to use `delete` every time you want to remove a string from the vector. Basically, you should never have to use `delete` on anything, and to accomplish that, you should avoid allocating memory with `new`. In this case, that means avoiding the use of `new char[/*...*/]`, which in turn means you should use `string` to store strings.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<char*> wordBank;` constructs an empty vector. As such, `wordBank[0]`, which uses [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), has undefined behavior since you're accessing out of bounds.

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

You can use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to add a new element, as such:

```
wordBank.push_back(new char[str.length + 1]);
```

Of course the most sensible thing is to just use use a `vector` of `strings`

```
vector<string> wordBank;
wordBank.push_back(str);
```

You're trying to manually manage memory for your strings, while the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class was designed to do that for you.

Also, from what you are describing your use case to be, you may wish to check out [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and/or [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). Here's a [tutorial](http://thispointer.com/stdset-tutorial-part-1-set-usage-details-with-default-sorting-criteria/).